# JCL - supply instream data to cataloged PROC

Tags: procedure, mainframe, jcl

I’m trying to replicate a case given by the book “Murach’s OS/390 and z/os JCL” (page 259), with the following code.

Briefly, I want to supply the instream dataset in the invoking job to the procedure invoked. And I have no clue why it’s not working.
Have anyone any suggestion?

(I know how to make it work without the instream dataset, but I want to replicate the case in the book)

**INVOKING JOB**

*XXXXXXX.PE000.UTILITY(SRCHCALL)*

```
000001 //JOB1 JOB                                                              
000002 //     JCLLIB ORDER=(XXXXXXX.PE000.UTILITY)                             
000003 //STEP01 EXEC PROVA                                                     
000004 //SRCHCA1.OUT1 DD *                                                     
000005 CIAO                                                                    
000006 /*                                                                      
000007 //
```

**PROCEDURE INVOKED**

*XXXXXXX.PE000.UTILITY(PROVA)*

```
000001 //EXMPLE  PROC                                                          
000002 //SRCHCA1 EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                              
000003 //OUTDD  DD DDNAME=OUT1
```

**JCL LISTING**

```
 1 //JOB1 JOB                                                    
  2 //     JCLLIB ORDER=(XXXXXXXX.PE000.UTILITY)                   
  3 //STEP01 EXEC PROVA                                           
  4 XXEXMPLE  PROC                                                
  5 XXSRCHCA1 EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                    
  6 XXOUTDD  DD DDNAME=OUT1                                       
  7 //SRCHCA1.OUT1 DD *
```

In the JCL listing, I was expecting to see also the string “CIAO”.

The code above is showing the exact syntax of the book, but by substituting the OUT1 in line 4 with OUTDD, I get to override line 3 of the proc only with the job’s overriding statement but not the next line (“CIAO”).

**JCL LISTING (2)**

```
5 XXSRCHCA1 EXEC PGM=IEFBR14  
6 //SRCHCA1.OUTDD DD *        
  X/OUTDD  DD DDNAME=OUT1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Instream data* is separated from the JCL by JES2/3 when it reads and interprets the JCL stream. The actual data for each instream data set is stored separately on the JES spool space. Think of this as a temporary data set. JES "links" the DD-statement to the corresponding data. The actual data is *never* reproduced in the JCL listing.

You can change your procedure *PROVA* to look like this:

```
//EXMPLE   PROC                                             
//SRCHCA1  EXEC PGM=IEBGENER
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD DUMMY
//SYSUT1   DD DDNAME=OUT1
//SYSUT2   DD SYSOUT=*
```

Then rerun your first JCL and you should see the text "CIAO" in the job output.
You can also run the second example, but here you will have to write:

```
//SRCHCA1.SYSUT1 DD *
CIAO
/*
```

Again, you should see "CIAO" in a separate output file ind the job output.

(Note that I have not actually run my samples.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to see how it works. </br>

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer, if it was useful to you?

Comment: Sorry, It was the first question on the platform